# Alt+Tab is not switching between windows on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not switching between windows. While on a terminal, when I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it only showed the effect of <kbd>Tab</kbd> which was:

> Display all 1784 possibilities? (y or n)

My <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is working fine as to get the panel menu. I have to do <kbd>Alt</kbd> + right-click.

Why isn't <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> working?

I'm using GNOME classic and not [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface)).

Comment: Did you try `Ctrl + Alt + Tab`

Comment: Yes I did. But alas with the same result as above.

Comment: Is this Unity 3D?

Comment: Nope. I uninstalled unity and installed Gnome. I'm using Gnome classic.

Comment: Okay, please add that information to your question please. =)

Comment: @harisibrahimkv: as soon as you are using a different desktop environment, you've got what is quite definitely a non-standard arrangement.

Comment: True. I checked my system-settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts and almost all of them were disabled. I assigned "Alt+Tab" to "Switch applications". However, when I do "Alt+Tab" I can only switch between the first two apps. Usually, in 10.04, you could hold down "alt" and hit "tab" as many times as you want to reach the app that you want to switch to. But here, when I hit "Tab" the second time, the app selector that pops up in the middle disappears leaving me on my current app itself.

Comment: This bug you are experiencing has already been documented as a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/971051). If you have queries, please post comments in the bug report. I am now proceeding to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I guess you can close it as my problem has been solved and as for others it has been filed as a bug report. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, just to finalize the answer, a reboot has done the trick for me after doing the following:

I went to system-settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts and almost all of them were disabled. I assigned "Alt+Tab" to "Switch applications". Then even though the problem specified in one of the comments above persisted, a reboot has solved the problem and I'm able to switch between windows without any problem.

Edit: Sometimes you have to reboot multiple times.

Answer (score 9):

I use Super + W and select from current open programs. not the best solution to this issue but it helps.

Answer (score 6):

I'm also using Gnome Classic (with effects or without them).
I have reported the [bug about Alt+Tab](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/989198), but Sebastien Bacher said that it is not a bug. I found that it's duplicate of [971051](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/971051). Let's make these bugs heater!

As temporary solution we can install CompizConfig Settings Manager and select 'Application Switcher' or 'Static Application Switcher' from Window Management group.