# Nautilus not showing on launcher and alt+tab

Tags: nautilus

When I launch nautilus in my system, the window appears but it is not showing on the launcher bar. The problem is that I cannot switch back to the already opened nautilus window after going to any other applications. Even <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> is not showing active nautilus window. if I want to go back to nautilus window I have to minimize or close all other windows and apps. 
I have tried to lock nautilus to the launcher but it is only opening new window without showing the already opened window

Comment: This is a bug that has been filed here:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1584449  However, someone may have come up with a work around for it:  http://askubuntu.com/a/769221/231142

Comment: This might be a solution for you. It was brought up in Ubuntu 12.04. See link here [setting Alt-Tab for app switcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126205/alttab-not-switching-between-windows-on-12-04)

Comment: They supposedly fixed that bug, but it's not working for me. Here's the new bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1646420

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Files app from dash / application switcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769063/missing-files-app-from-dash-application-switcher)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nautilus windows don't show up in Launcher](http://askubuntu.com/questions/779514/nautilus-windows-dont-show-up-in-launcher)